# Application Server : Limit the number of concurrent client connections

Tags: jakarta-ee, application-server

Is there an application server where I can set a defined maximum of concurrent client connections?
Also no connections should be queued.

Comment: take in mind that an app server offers services to different kinds of clients, the web container and ejb container can define their own limits.  Which one are you interested in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly every application server has a feature which is similar to what you want.

In Glassfish you have the possibility to use the so called `Connection Pooling` which nearly does what you want. It limits the number of concurrent client connections to the size of the connection pool. Normally it will queue the requests which are above the limitation, but you can also just disable the queueing (or if not possible set it to 1).

Here is a link with detailed information: [GlassFish Tuning - HTTP Connection Queue & Keep Alive](https://blogs.oracle.com/binublog/entry/glassfish_tuning_http_connection_queue)

In Tomcat you have an option called `maxConnections` which does exactly what you want, but be aware that Tomcat is not a Java EE application server (you may check TomEE).

Here is a link with some Tomcat information: [Tomcat HTTP Connector Configuration Attributes](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation)

In JBoss there is something similar, you have the option `maxThreads` which is effectivly the same as maximum connections.

Here is some information about JBoss: [JBoss HTTP Connector Configuration Parameters](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/config/http.html)

Comment: tried #asadmin server.http-service.connection-pool.max-pending-count = 1 | leads to a command set failed exception. Seems like I can not access any *connection-pool* settings.

Comment: You have to use it like this: `asadmin set server.http-service.connection-pool.max-pending-count=1`

Comment: Maybe I should be more specific - the exact exception is "no configuration found for server.http-service.connection-pool.max-pending-count" - Do I have to create or enable connection pooling first?

Comment: You don't have to create something. You can also use the Glassfish Admin GUI to configure it.

Comment: Im sorry. I cant find anything about connection pooling within the glassfish admin GUI too, which would explain the "cant find configuration" exception maybe.

Comment: It can be found under `server-config` then `Network Config` then `Listeners` in `http-listener-1` in the tab `HTTP` you can set `maxConnections` or in `server-config` under `Thread Pools` you can set the max queue size for the `http-thread-pool`.